# How do you express $\nu_2(n)$ as a SymPy expression so that SymPy's simplification algorithm supports it?

Tags: reference-request, math-software, python, programming, computer-algebra-systems

$\nu_2(n)$ is the completely additive arithmetic function that is the maximum power $k$ such that $2^k \mid n$.

How do I use SymPy to represent this function.  I can calculate it by hand doing:

```
def v_2(n:int) -> int:
   k = 0
   while n % 2 == 0:
       n /= 2
       k += 1
   return k
```

However, I don't think this will be compatible with SymPy's expression trees, which have rearrangement and simplification capabilities.  In other words Sympy can't unwind that code and determine that $X^{v_2(4Y)} /X^{v_2(Y)}$ can be simplified to $X^2$.

So I want SymPy to know how to simplify even under the property $\nu_2(nm) = \nu_2(n) + \nu_2(m)$.

Is this possible or do I need to look into another CAS that supports it?

Comment: Is it equivalent to counting the number of zeros at the end of the binary expression?

Comment: @VezenBU  Yes, for the $p = 2$ case

Comment: Then is there any specific reason that you want to use the SymPy library?

Comment: @VezenBU SymPy is the goto lib for CAS in Python.  Python is simple since I have experience in it.

Comment: @VezenBU I'm also comfortable in C++ if that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of experience with SymPy. But I think it's at least possible to define a class where we maintain the v2 value for each instance, i.e., each number. When we do a multiplication "c = a*b", we may assign "c.v2 = a.v2 + b.v2". Besides, since as we have confirmed, v2 is equivalent to the number of zeros at the end of the binary expression, the quantity is immediately available. For other p values, maintaining a sequence of base-p is possible, IMO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134082/discussion-between-vezen-bu-and-penandpapermathematics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), especially the expand_log (https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#expand-log), we can see a similar existing simplification on the logarithm.

Therefore, we at least can extend log and expand-log to implement $\nu_2$.

Comment: Yes, but $\log$ maps into $\Bbb{R}$ so would require a flooring in general.  How will SymPy know that $\lfloor \log_2(nm)\rfloor = \lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor + \lfloor \log_2(m)\rfloor$?